# Woocomerce Product Page Tab Text Color How to change?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6lCI.png)I have tried to make changes in the text color of Dimensions under Additional Informatoin under Tabs Woocommerce Product Page using theme customise option in wordpress, but the customise option doesn't have any option to change the color of the text. The Text I have circled is Additional Information -> Dimensions. Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.woocommerce table.shop_attributes th
{
    color: red
}
.woocommerce table.shop_attributes td p
{
   color: green
}
```

To change color,  you need to override above css  !! you can try   http://prntscr.com/qi4qfk